# Standard visitor UK visa application- error noticed after submission

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

Is it considered a negative point while you apply and mentioned in the form by mistake old telephone numbers of close family members which were provided in the last successful visa application. By mistake i didn't put the updated address details and telephone numbers of family members in uk and put the old ones which were mentioned in the previous successful application and now bio metrics submitted already. No room for correction now. 
**however at the same time the sponsors details are 100% correct like address and telephone number.
** The home address of family members are correct except one address
***inserted old telephone numbers by mistake.

Any feedback for above dumb mistake would be much appreciated.
**Received 6,2 and 5 years UK visitor visa in the past with good schengen travel history.

Comment: It is highly unprobable that anyone would call your family members so no one will know you gave wring numbers.

Comment: Please DO NOT edit your questions deleting all the text.

Comment: Can you please clarify the exact question? As it's written it's hard to tell.